# Node/Express Cannot Open CSS or JS Files

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nginx, npm

I once installed node and express via npm in my Windows laptop. I put my `node_modules` folder in a same directory as my `app.js`.  Everything works fine including some attempt serving static files.

```
app.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

I can play with this directory, even with `index.html` (auto-default page if I open `/static/somedir`) and its `style.css`.

Later, I tried to move it to my **linux** vps (node installed) to see how is it look like, it was proxied with nginx.

All my view works fine, but my `.css`, and `.js` *extension* files always return ***404***.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski can you elaborate? as shown, my full url i put my static files is `mysite:port/static`, and my static folder path on disk is `public`, I can't access my `public/somescript.js` from `mysite:port/static/somescript.js`. I'm pretty sure this was explained in my question.

Comment: What you just listed was what I was asking about. And, given the details provided, seems like it should be working as expected. That suggests there's something else at play. Perhaps the use of Nginx. It may be configured to serve static files itself rather than deferring them to your Node application as it's doing with the routes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited my `/sites-available/default` config in nginx to take over static files

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name mysite;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://myip:myport;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

solution found on https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-14-04